# Debugger does not hit breakpoints on assemblies

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

In a web application I can't debug an assembly, but I can debug some others.

I have a tool that build some assemblies on a network path using CSC (with /debug param) and at the end of the compilation assemblies and pdbs are **copied** in the local site bin folder; for example are build two assemblies:

1. webui.dll
2. webbiz.dll

I have a middle assembly **webframework.dll** used from webui and webbiz that shows some methods used from them.

The situation when I'm facing the issue is the following:

- from an httphandler I call a method of webui.dll using `Assembly.Load`, here I can debug webui's methods
- following the code I call a method of webframework, here I can debug its methods too
- following the code I call a webframework method, that handle other assemblies calls; here from a delegate is called a webbiz method using `Assembly.LoadFile`...here I can debug webframework methods, but ***not*** webbiz

Here I'm totally confused, and I can't find a solution.

Some info:

1. the webapp is runnig under IIS not IIS express
2. all assemblies are compiled for the debug and pdbs are fresh and not corrupted
3. if I try to `Step Into` the webbiz method I see `The application in in break mode` and I must hit `Continue execution`
4. I'm using VS2015, with VS2013 was working fine (!)
5. it's an ASP .NET related issue, because if I try to reproduce the issue on a console application I can debug
6. if I put the webbiz assembly in a path different from `bin` I can debug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to solve the issue is to use `Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile`